# Q: Idiomatic way to check if any of variable is not null in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Let's suppose I have Kotlin code like this:

```
val var1:String? = isVar1Present() 
val var2:String? = isVar2Present()
val var3:String? = isVar3Present()

   
if ((var1!=null)||(var2!=null)||(var3!=null)) {
//do something complex only if at least one of var is not null and do it only one time
}
```

How to make it more ideomatic in Kotlin? If it was one var - it would be simple `var1?.let { ... }`  but I have 3 of them here.

I also thought about

```
    if (listOf(var1, var2, var3)
            .filterNotNull()
            .isNotEmpty( ) { 
                //do something complex 
             }
```

but it looks rather crazy (but short, especially that in real code is not `isVarNPresent` but rather long line like `isVar1Present=varmanager.getStatusOfVar(varmanager.var1)` (so example above will be using additional map step)

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way, and the parentheses around the operation could be removed because `!=` has more precedence than `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slightly shorter version:

```
if (var1 ?: var2 ?: var3 != null) { … }
```

(That works because `var1 ?: var2 ?: var3` gives the first non-null value found, or  null only if all three variables are null.)

That's slightly shorter, and arguably slightly more idiomatic — but a little less obvious, especially to non-Kotlin-experts.  Depending on who's likely to read the code, it may be worth sticking with the simpler, more easily understandable version (with the parens removed, as Animesh suggests):

```
if (var1 != null || var2 != null || var3 != null) { … }
```

Alternatively, if you need to use that first non-null value inside the block, you could use:

```
(var1 ?: var2 ?: var3)?.let { … }
```

In that case, the less-idiomatic alternative would be a lot longer, so the construct is more justified.

Answer (score 1):

For the list operation, I'd write it as

```
listOf(var1, var2, var3).any { it != null }
```

Comment: Or `listOfNotNull(var1, var2, var3).isNotEmpty()`